# Integrity constraint in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about Integrity constraints

What is the difference between these two requests :

```
Create table t1 (c1 foreign key references t2(c2), ...)
```

and

```
Create table t1 (c1 references t2(c2), ...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference; they will both create a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. The underlying metadata as a result is identical, and when you script each table, SQL Server will generate a `CREATE TABLE` script with a separate `ALTER TABLE ... ADD FOREIGN KEY` statement for adding the constraint.

The first form is preferred because it is explicit; when you say `FOREIGN KEY` you know it's going to be a `FOREIGN KEY`; when you don't, it might be ambiguous to folks who don't know all of the nuances and optional elements to DDL syntax.

Note that in both cases they will create a *system-named* `FOREIGN KEY` constraint (e.g. `FK__t1__c1__35BCFE0A` or `FK__t1__c1__37A5467C` - unnecessarily cryptic only to prevent conflict with other constraint names). Best practice suggests you should explicitly name your constraints, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1
(
   c1 ...,
   CONSTRAINT fk_t1_t2 FOREIGN KEY(c1) REFERENCES dbo.t2(c2)
);
```

Comment: +1 for the **explicit naming** ! I was just going to write a comment to that effect. Also: the column `c1` also needs a **datatype** to be valid.....

Comment: @marc_s yeah I left that as `...`